# Close HTML tag on when typing ">" in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm looking for a way to close HTML tags but when pressing `>`. I've found a lot of answers like typing tab each time (really ?) or when typing `</` after.

What I'd like is to type : `<div` and when I press `>` it would output automatically `<div>X</div>` And place the cursor on the X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [snippet](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/top-features-of-sublime-text/quickly-insert-text-and-code-with-sublime-text-snippets/), or use one of [these](https://github.com/aslamdoctor/SublimeText2-HTML-Snippets).

See Sublime Text [Snippet Reference](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html)